# nginx limit_req works но отдает 404

Tags: nginx

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла проблема с nginx.

В секции http

```
limit_req_status 403;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr  zone=two:10m rate=5r/m;
```

в хосте sites-available

```
location /api/public/symbols {  limit_req zone=two nodelay;
                            }
```

В итоге домен/api/public/symbols отдается 404 до тех пор, пока не превысим количество запросов (т.е. контента нет). Если закомментить записи - всё работает. С чем может быть связано?

Comment: Покажите весь конфиг

Comment: Просто скопируйте location в котором раньше обрабатывался этот запрос

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XdHXWA53 и https://pastebin.com/1xcdM1zC